# insert values from a list in specific format in textbox python

Tags: python, list, collections, tkinter, counter

I am currently using Python 2.7, with Tkinter and collections. I have got my program to count the words in a `.txt` file and save it to a variable. However when I `resultsBox.insert(END, document_data_Tally )` its displays it like `Counter({'Test': 2, 'World': 1, 'Hello': 1})`.

I am trying to get it into the format of

```
Word : Value Word : Value
Word : Value Word : Value
Word : Value Word : Value
```

I want it to do that for 10 lines and and then start on the next column.

```
import os
from Tkinter import *
from collections import Counter
import tkFileDialog

root = Tk()

root.title("Doc Word Frequency")
root.geometry("600x300")

def close_window (): 
    root.destroy()

def browse_directory():
    global filename
    filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=root,title='Choose a file')

    inputBox.delete(0, "end")
    inputBox.insert(0, filename)

def read_document():
    with open (os.path.basename(filename), "r") as myfile:
        document_data = myfile.read().replace('\n', '')

    document_data_list = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  document_data).split()

    document_data_Tally = Counter(document_data_list)

    print(document_data_list)

    resultsBox.configure(state=NORMAL)
    resultsBox.insert(END, document_data_Tally )
    resultsBox.configure(state=DISABLED)

inputBox = Entry(root, width = 50)
inputBox.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 20, pady = 20)
inputBox.insert(0, 'Upload Document')

Button(root, width = 9, text = 'Browse', command = browse_directory).grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W, padx = 4)
Button(root, width = 9, text = 'Read', command = read_document).grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = W, padx = 4)
Button(root, width = 9, text = 'Quit', command = close_window).grid(row = 0, column = 3, sticky = W, padx = 4)

resultsBox = Text(root, width = 60, height = 10)
resultsBox.grid(columnspan = 4, padx = 10, pady = 10)
resultsBox.config(state=DISABLED)

mainloop( )
```

PS. I am quite new to Python and any constructive criticism would be appreciated.

Comment: The results of the Counter() call is returning a Counter object. When you add it to your box, it is doing a __repr__() call to it and that is what you are seeing. Instead, you need to parse the Counter object and format your own string. Treat the Counter object like a dict to loop through the words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to extract the data from the counter object before putting it into the Text:

```
data = '\n'.join('{}\t{}'.format(k, v) for k, v in document_data_Tally.iteritems())

resultsBox.configure(state=NORMAL)
resultsBox.insert(END, data)
resultsBox.configure(state=DISABLED)
```

This builds a list that  separates the words and their counts with a tab on their own line, so you should see something similar to below in your `resultsBox`:

```
Test    2 
World   1 
Hello   1
```